xcodeでunityのデータを実機テストしようとするとエラーになります
Unityで作成した2Dゲームをiphoneで実機テストしたいのですが、
Unity-iphone の signing & capabilitiesタブで下記２つのエラーが出ます。
Communication with Apple failed
Your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile. Connect a device to use or manually add device IDs in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. https://developer.apple.com/account/
No profiles for 'com.ebiharamiyako.ClimbCloud' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.（会社名）.（プログラム名）'.
また、実行するデバイスを選択する欄に「Any iOS Device」が出てこず、接続したiPhone se2が選択できません。
どうすればiPhone se2でテストできるでしょうか？
＊有料のApple Developer Programには登録していません。
＊macのfinderにiPhoneが表示されているので、接続自体はされているようです
＊Applleのdevelopperサイトの「Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.」という項目が関係するのかな？と思いましたが、権限の関係なのかこの項目自体にアクセスができませんでした
macOS ： 13.6.9
iphone SE2 : iOS 17.6.1
Unity ： 2022.3.40f1
Xcode ： Version 15.2 (15C500b)

apple developperの「」
